# Conditional Validation on a text field

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a text field and I want to have a validation which verify if it starts with 0 the length will be 10, else will be 13.

I want to know if I can write in validation expression like "^0..." not in function.

I hope you can help me.

I code in ASP.NET, C#.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Text="dsg" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="[^0]{0-10},[^1]{0-13}" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This doesn't work , but I want something like this.

Comment: I use it but i don't know for sure how to write the expression

Comment: .try this [^0]{10,13}

Comment: "^0\d{9}$|^w*\d{12}$"  with this is working with 0 but i don't know how to say  'everything' . i tried with w* but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`[^0]{0-10}` means from 0 up to 10 characters **not equal** to `0`.</strike> The `^` does not have the same meaning in the beginning of the regular expression and later.

A regular expression for a string of 10 characters starting with `0` is `^0.{9}$`.

The other is `^[^0].{12}$`.

So together: `^(0.{9}|[^0].{12})$`

Comment: thank you. it worked. do you know how to add at this numeric type ? i want only numbers

Comment: @RalucaIonescu Replace `.` (which means any character) with `[0-9]`.

Comment: `{0-10}` does not mean *0 up to 10 characters*. It matches a literal substring `{0-10}`. [Here, look](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b0-10%7d&i=%7b0-10%7d&o=m).

Answer (score 2):

Your regex `[^0]{0-10},[^1]{0-13}` means:

- `[^0]` - Match anything but `0` (even a comma)
- `{0-10},` - Match literal string `{0-10},` (because of the hyphen inside `{...}`)
- `[^1]` - Match anything but `1`
- `{0-13}` - Match literal `{0-13}` string.

If you plan to use only server-side validation, you can use .NET regex to validate

> if it starts with 0 the length will be 10 , else will be 13.
>   :

```
^(0)?(?(1)\d{9}|\d{13})$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(0)%3F(%3F(1)%5Cd%7B9%7D%7C%5Cd%7B13%7D)%5Cr%3F%24&i=0123456789%0D%0A1234567890123%0D%0A12345678901230&o=m)

In case you also plan to use it on the client side, you will need a JavaScript regex flavor where you cannot use conditionals:

```
^(?:0\d{9}|\d{13})$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD7xA6/1)